# What is the value of $|A \cap B|$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

For $A$ and $B$ sets,

$|B \times (A \cup B)| = 108$, $|A - B| = 3$ and $|B-A| = 5$

What is the value of $|A \cap B|$?

I see that there's cartesian product. What should I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x =|A\cap B|$, then $|A| = x+3$, $|B|= 5+x$ and $|A\cup B| = x+8$.

Now solve $$(x+5)(x+8) =|B|\cdot |A\cup B| = |B\times (A\cup B)|=108$$

Since $0=x^2+13x-68 = (x+17)(x-4)$ we get the solution $x=4.$

Comment: Can you be more clear? How did you get that?

Comment: Will I solve for $(x+5)(x+8) = 108$?

Comment: Yes, can you do that?

Comment: I'm gonna try lol. I think I can't. Any hints? Hold on, let me try again

Comment: Can you give any hint for solving?

Comment: Where did this come from $0=x^2+13x-68$?

Comment: $108 = (x+5)(x+8) = x^2+13x+40$ so $x^2+13x-68=0$

Comment: Got it now! Thanks for perfectly answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is known that $\vert A \cup B \vert = \vert A \vert + \vert B \vert - \vert A \cap B \vert$.

You need to understand that $\vert A \vert = \vert A \cap B \vert + \vert A-B \vert \;$ and $\;\vert B \vert = \vert A \cap B \vert + \vert B-A \vert$.

Then, you can use the procedure that John Watson uses in his answer.

Comment: I think you want *minus* $|A\cap B|$ on your first line.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a mistake. Thanks.